# What does "que lo que" ("klk" in chat) mean?

Tags: saludos, jerga-internet, república-dominicana

Whenever I talk to a friend (Dominican I believe) via chat like Gtalk, he always starts the conversation with:

> klk

I did some research about that and found that, in fact, it comes from the Spanish "que lo que". So, what does that mean? Is it some kind of Dominican "hello"?

Comment: Probably "Qué (es lo que) dices?" something like "Qué es lo que tienes para decir/contar?"

Comment: Comentario proviniente de una [sugerencia de edición](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14973): _No, “ya tú sabe” no significa lo mismo que “que lo que”. “Ya tú sabe” se usa más bien como “ya me entiendes”. También es común usarlo con gente con quien tienes complicidad en una conversación para no terminar de contar alguna historia si hay alguien más delante (p.ej.: vi al chico que me gusta y ... ya tú sabe)_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a Dominican slang way of saying "*what's up*" (or even *WTF*), most likely coming from "*¿qué es lo que esta pasando?*" (*What's happening?* or *What's going on?*), suppressing the *s* in a way like this:

¿*Qué es lo que... (está pasando, pasa, etc)?* > *¿Qué eh lo que...?* > *¿Qué e lo que...?* > *¿Qué'e lo que...?* > *¿Qué lo que...?*

Comment: In Canary islands we have a similar construction "¿Qué cuál?" where the same etimology can not be used, but the meaning is the same.

Comment: but its only for dominican spanish in other hispanic countries they don't understand this, and thinks you're nuts xd

Answer (score 2):

It means `What's up`. It's just like saying `Ya tu sabe`.